# Как подключить счетчик JS на несколько товаров?

Tags: javascript

Есть несколько товаров в интернет-магазине. У каждого должен быть счетчик выбранного кол-ва. После выгрузки товаров из БД все классы и идентификаторы повторяются, и у меня выходит взаимодействовать только с одним счетчиком.
Как сделать, чтобы у каждого товара был работающий счетчик?
P.S. Просьба предлагать решения на чистом JS.

```js
var plus = document.querySelectorAll ('.plus');
var minus = document.querySelectorAll('.minus');
var number = document.querySelectorAll('.number');
var i = 0;

plus[i].onclick = up;
function up() {
  var count = Number(number[i].innerHTML);
  number[i].innerHTML = count += 1;
}
minus[i].onclick = down;
function down() {
  var count = Number(number[i].innerHTML);
  number[i].innerHTML = count -= 1; 
}
```

```html
<div class="count">
  <div class="minus" id="minus">
    -
  </div>
  <div class="number" id="number">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="plus" id="plus">
    +
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно проходить по всем блокам `.count` и добавлять обработчики клика в рамках конкретного блока:

```js
function addHandlers(count) {
  var minus = count.querySelector(".minus");
  var number = count.querySelector(".number");
  var plus = count.querySelector(".plus");
  plus.addEventListener("click", function() {
    number.innerText++;
  });
  minus.addEventListener("click", function() {
    number.innerText--;
  });
}

var counts = document.querySelectorAll(".count");
counts.forEach(addHandlers);
```

```css
.minus, .number, .plus {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="count">
  <div class="minus">-</div>
  <div class="number">1</div>
  <div class="plus">+</div>
</div>
<div class="count">
  <div class="minus">-</div>
  <div class="number">1</div>
  <div class="plus">+</div>
</div>
<div class="count">
  <div class="minus">-</div>
  <div class="number">1</div>
  <div class="plus">+</div>
</div>
```

---

ID элементов должны быть уникальны. В данной ситуации вполне можно обойтись только классами, так что, возможно, стоит отказаться от использования id здесь

Comment: Все отлично работает!
А как сделать чтоб прибавлялось не 1 , а 0,5 ?

Comment: @orel-22 `number.innerText = +number.innerText + 0.5;`

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень пригодилось!